# SB-KERNEL:TWO-ARG - what does this mean when used in debugger backtrace?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm (a newbie) debugging my Lisp code (Common Lisp, Steel Bank, SLIME).

The first frame in my backtrace is:

```
0: (SB-KERNEL:TWO-ARG-> 1 NIL)
```

My question is:

- what exactly does "SB-KERNEL:TWO-ARG" mean/check/do ?
- where should I have looked this up online myself?  (I tried searching for it but cann't find any reference to it other than in other Backtrace outputs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "v" on a frame to jump to the definition of the function in the debugger.

In this case, the function `sb-kernel:two-arg->` sounds like a specialized version of `>` that is called when there are exactly two arguments provided. If the arguments are 1 and NIL, you'll get an error because NIL is not a number.

I'm not sure how you'd figure this out yourself, except by practicing and asking questions.

Comment: When I hit v I get "Error: failed to find the WRITE-DATE of /usr/share/sbcl-source/src/code/numbers.lisp", infact numbers.lisp isn't on my computer at all.

Comment: An easy way to get around that is build SBCL from source and install it.